# Meaning of the phrasal verb "pull out" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

Could you tell me what *pull out* means in this context?

> Michael: That’s crazy. That’s crazy talk! Meredith! The Merenator, sleepin’ with suppliers! Hoo-ooh! Wow! What time we got? [checks watch] You know what? That’s a good place to end it. Right there. This, I think, was a great ethics seminar. She has given us a lot of wonderful things to think about. Right… what is wrong. Who’s to say? Really. In the end. I mean because it is… unknowable. But, let’s give her a round of applause. Holly, everybody. Holly! Get back to work. [everyone applauds, then leaves] [to Holly] Great job. I am truly impressed. That, uh, you really **pulled** that one **out**. Classic. Classic meeting. We should celebrate.

It's from the second episode of the fifth episode of *The Office*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

She [pulled it off](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pull-off-something) (another way to put it, I believe they are synonymous), she succeeded in giving a seminar on business ethics. The meeting went great, in Michael's opinion. It was a classic (excellent, of high quality) meeting (again, from Michael's perspective :) )